# Set up class delegate from UITabBarController

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

All,

After my previous experiences I am a little reluctant to ask this - but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere...

I have 2 viewcontrollers in a uitabbarcontroller. One of them is a settings table - the other is the main view controller for my app. There are controls I would like to update in the main view controller when a setting is changed.

I've set up a delegate method in the settings view controller to that should allow this - but obviously as the settings view controller is not called from the main view controller - it doesn't work using the normal set up.

Is there anyway I can used the tabbarcontroller to set up the delegate relationship when the app starts?

I greatly appreciate any help that can be given.

Many thanks in advance...

Steve

Comment: Incidentally, I have tried setting up the view controllers in the viewDidLoad method of the tabbarcontroller class - it lets me set the objects equal to the viewcontrollers - but then it errors when I try to set delegate...

Comment: Problem solved... I had forgotten that I have Navigation VC's between the TabBarVC and the main and settings VC's!

Comment: Please put your solution in as an answer and mark it as accepted (for book keeping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... I had forgotten that I have Navigation VC's between the TabBarVC and the main and settings VC's!